# Programmatically change font properties in email body

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have been successfully programming this in PowerPoint VBA but haven't been able to make it work on Outlook.

1. I have an email ready to be sent in Outlook 2013
2. I want to scan the body of the email for bold text (i.e., bold characters) and change its color to red
3. (nice to have) Exclude from the macro the signature

I tried several attempts with "Substitute", "if"-loop but no success. Thanks a lot for putting me on the right track.

---

The following code converts the color of the body but does not discriminate for bold words. Any ideas?

```
Public Sub FormatSelectedText()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector

    ' Add reference to Word library
    ' in VBA Editor, Tools, References
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next

'Reference the current Outlook item
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection


            ' replace the With block with your code
                   With objSel
                   ' Formatting code goes here
                        '.Font.Size = 18
                        If .Font.Bold = True Then
                            .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
                        End If
                        .Font.Color = wdColorRed
                        '.Font.Italic = True
                        '.Font.Name = "Arial"
                   End With

            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Discussion continued here 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263050/programmatically-change-properties-in-email-body-in-outlook-with-vba

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN.

You can use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items to get the HTML content of the message body or use the Word object model to get the job done. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the WOM (Word object model). See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.